# Changed my code from python 2 to 3 and trying to run this Unix

Tags: python-3.x, unix, urllib

I was able to run the below code in python 2.7 in Windows correctly. But when I converted and changed my code from 2.7 to Python 3.6, then trying to run the code in Unix. I am getting the following error.
'TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.'
I am very new to this URLLIB. It would be great help if you could tell me what is the problem in my code.

python 2.7, windows 10:

```
import json
import win32com.client as WC


def extractFromParFiles_SingleComponent (HCP_ID,ListOfTestnumbers,ListOfPartSequenceNumbers):
    InputObject = {"HCP_ID":HCP_ID,"ListOfTestnumbers":ListOfTestnumbers,"ListOfPartSequenceNumbers":ListOfPartSequenceNumbers,"KeepNullValues":True}

    return callWebservice(InputObject)

def callWebservice(InputObject):

    URL = ""

    h = WC.Dispatch('WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1')
    h.SetAutoLogonPolicy(0)
    h.SetTimeouts(0,0,0,0)
    h.Open('POST', URL, False)
    h.SetRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

    JSON_In = json.dumps(InputObject)
    h.Send(JSON_In)
    JSON_Out = h.responseText

    try:
        OutputData = json.loads(JSON_Out)
    except:
        print JSON_Out

    if "d" in OutputData:
        return OutputData["d"]
    else:
        print "Length of JSON_In: %s\n" % len(JSON_In)
        print "JSON_In: %s\n" % JSON_In
        print "Length of JSON_Out: %s\n" % len(JSON_Out)
        print "JSON_Out: %s\n" % JSON_Out
        raise RuntimeError, "Error from Webservice"
```

Python 3.6, Unix:

```
import json
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse
from ntlm3 import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler


def extractFromParFiles_SingleComponent(HCP_ID,ListOfTestnumbers,ListOfPartSequenceNumbers):

    InputObject = {"HCP_ID":HCP_ID,"ListOfTestnumbers":ListOfTestnumbers,"ListOfPartSequenceNumbers":ListOfPartSequenceNumbers,"KeepNullValues":True}

    return callWebservice(InputObject)



def callWebservice(InputObject):

    URL = ""

    User = ""  
    Password = ""

    pass_item = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    pass_item.add_password(None, URL, User, Password)
    auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(pass_item)          
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

    JSON_In = json.dumps(InputObject)

    req = urllib.request.Request(URL, JSON_In, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    JSON_Out = f.read()
    f.close()

    OutputData = json.loads(JSON_Out)

    return OutputData["d"]
```

Answer (score 1):

`urllib.request.Request` data parameter expects a bytes-like object, you're passing in a string.  Call `encode()` on `JSON_In` to convert it to a byte array.

From the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request):

*data* must be an object specifying additional data to send to the server, or `None` if no such data is needed. Currently HTTP requests are the only ones that use *data*. The supported object types include bytes, file-like objects, and iterables. If no `Content-Length` nor `Transfer-Encoding` header field has been provided, HTTPHandler will set these headers according to the type of data. `Content-Length` will be used to send bytes objects, while `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` as specified in RFC 7230, Section 3.3.1 will be used to send files and other iterables.

Your code should then look like:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(URL, JSON_In.encode(), {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Comment: I changed the code, but I get the following error. 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized'

Comment: Why not use `opener.open(...)` directly instead of `urllib.request.Request`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.OpenerDirector.open